# Difference between "**/*/" and "**/"?

Tags: ruby

Here are two ways to use `glob` to recursively list directories:

`Dir.glob("**/*/")`

`Dir.glob("**/")`

The output appears to be the same, at least for a small subtree.  Is there a difference between those two commands I am missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ** matches 0 or more directories. By placing a * at the end you remove directories in the root, essentially making it 1 or more:

```
 a = Dir.glob('/tmp/**/*/').sort     
 b = Dir.glob('/tmp/**/').sort.size
 b.size => 19
 a.size => 18
 b - a =>  ["/tmp/"]
```

Without a leading constant path though, it doesn't look like there is a difference as 0 length matches aren't interesting and don't get put in the results.

Answer (score 0):

In that case no there isn't.

But, there are cases where that type of distinction can be important.  If the patterns were instead `**/*` and `**/*/*` to recursively match files rather than directories, the first one would include files in the current directory while the latter would only list files that were at least one level down from the current directory since the `/*/` in the middle has to match something.